# Can not parse json format with SBJson?

Tags: objective-c

I can not parse json format in object C when i use SBJson json class. Follow format:

```
{ls:{
lnk:"http:\/\/vn.com\/vn",
set:[
{n:"ABC",id:10},
{n:"ABC",id:11},
]
}}
```

How to parse this format with SBJson OR anyway. 
Thanks!

Comment: That is invalid JSON. Create valid JSON and you will be able to parse it.

Comment: Really? I don't think so.
Case 1: if i use quote, it parse OK
{"ls":{ 
"lnk":"http:\/\/vn.com\/vn", 
"set":[ 
{"n":"ABC","id":"10"}, 
{"n":"ABC","id":"11"}, 
] 
}} 

Case 2: if i use quote (but not all), it parse not OK
{"ls":{ 
"lnk":"http:\/\/vn.com\/vn", 
"set":[ 
{"n":"ABC","id":"10"}, 
{"n":"ABC","id":"11"}, 
] 
}} 

Case 3: my question above, it parse not OK
{ls:{ 
lnk:"http:\/\/vn.com\/vn", 
set:[ 
{n:"ABC",id:10}, 
{n:"ABC",id:11}, 
] 
}}

Comment: This is my app error:  -JSONValue failed. Error is: Illegal start of token [l]

Comment: So? Then you know the answer: Keys must be in double quotes. Only then it is valid JSON. `{foo: "bar"}` is not valid, `{"foo": "bar"}` is. I don't understand your question. If you already know how make so that it can be parsed, why do you ask?

Comment: Hi, i know json format: http://www.json.org/. But my customer want above format and i can not parse it with sbjson. That's my question.

Comment: Then tell him that it does not make sense to use a custom format in this case and that he should use JSON. What's the problem with adding quotes?

Comment: I don't know, with case 2, it's error: My app log: -JSONValue failed. Error trace is: ( "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Unrecognised leading character\" UserInfo=0x4e59e50 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unrecognised leading character}"

Comment: Maybe data in json format. I Fixed. Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, strings must be between quotes. The second error is that there's a comma after the second element of the set. Here's the corrected JSON (you can use a [validator](http://jsonlint.com/) to be sure):

```
{
    "ls": {
        "lnk": "http://vn.com/vn",
        "set": [
            {
                "n": "ABC",
                "id": 10
            },
            {
                "n": "ABC",
                "id": 11
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with this json format, but it's error. My app log: 
-JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Unrecognised leading character\" UserInfo=0x4e59e50 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unrecognised leading character}"